# Aligning background sprite images

Tags: html, css, html-table

How can i center align background images in a td or a li which have different widths (from 25px to 30px). I tried everything but they won't align.

This is what i'm using:

```
.cIcons-26 {
float: left;
position:relative;
height:26px;
background:url("../img/sprites/icons/png") top left no-repeat;
}

.theIcon { background-position: -93px -1px; }
```

Comment: `.cIcons-26` is a `td`?

Answer (score 0):

you should start by using the ../img/sprites/icons.png, not the

> "../img/sprites/icons/png"

I don't understand :

> widths (from 25px to 30px)

you whant to align both to have the image on the same place, or just the image centered for both?

If you use `background-position: center;` or`background-position: 50% 50%;` it should be centered. How it looks depends on de width and height of the outside content.

Comment: the images have different widths. some are 20px, 23px 26px. The problem is that they wont align in center

Comment: with 'background-position:50% 50%' they should. if they are nor centered correctly you could used separated 'top:x' 'lef:x' etc. untill you get the result you want